# Can someone help me how to set the classpath for maven on windows 7

Tags: maven-3

I am trying to set the class path on win 7 and after doing all the necessary variables when I try to execute mvn --version I am getting this error -"mvn is not recognized" 
In system variable I have set M2_HOME and the value is set to --- C:\Users\Amzi\Desktop\apache-maven-3.0.4-bin
in to the path variable at the end I have set the value like
;C:\Users\Amzi\Desktop\apache-maven-3.0.4-bin\bin
can someone help me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks

Comment: You have to set the path in Windows itself to make windows able to find the command mvn.

Comment: How to set the path in windows

Answer (score 0):

To run maven from command line in Windows 7 you should have properly set JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME & PATH environment variables in the following table:

```
    Start button -> Computer menu item -> Properties on right click menu item -> 
Advanced System Settings button on left panel -> Advanced tab in System Properties dialog ->
 Environment Variables button -> System variables table
```

`JAVA_HOME` set to directory where JDK is installed:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06
```

`M2_HOME` set to extraction directory of Maven distribution:

```
C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.4
```

Additional entries in `PATH` for JDK and Maven binaries:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;
```